# Populating other jcombox that refers to the first jcombobox

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jcombobox

Hi I am new here and I need some help in populating other jcomboboxes. All I wanted is that if I will select Last name from the first combobox, the other combobox will be populated by First names of patients/persons that has same Lastnames same as the Middlename. I hope you can help me

here's the pic:[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMY0x.png)

As of now this is the code that I got to get values from database and put it on the first jcombobox:

```
public void lastname(){
    try{
        Connection  con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javaclinic", "root","");
        String sql1 = "select * from patient";
        PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();

        while(rs1.next()){

           lastn.addItem(rs1.getString("PLastname"));

        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

    }
}
```

Comment: *"Hi I am new here and I need some help in.."* ..using the search function? This same question is asked every couple of days. Please use the search function in future. Start here -> [`JComboBox` Q&As](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jcombobox).

Answer (score 1):

Modify the sql to search database , if user enter any value like:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM patient";
if(lastName.equals(""))
{
    sql1 +=" WHERE PLastName = '" + lastName + "'";
}
```